# How to define a list with data similar to the result of a Snowflake cursor.description?

Tags: python, list, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, pytest, database-cursor

```
cursor.execute("select * from table)
desc = cursor.description
```

print(desc)

> > [ResultSetMetadata(name='id', type='', prescision=20 ...),ResultSetMetadata(name='name', type='', prescision=20...)]

print(type(desc)

> > class 'list'

I want to define a list which is same as desc but it throws an error `'name 'ResultSetMetadata' is not defined'`.

```
desc = [ResultSetMetadata(name='id', type='', prescision=20 ...),ResultSetMetadata(name='name', type='', prescision=20...)]
```

Is there a way to define the list?

I am trying to write a unit test code where I have to mock the result of cursor.description.

```
mock_cursor.description = desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access `ResultSetMetadata` without importing it first. I looked through the docs but I couldn't find the path to import it. Instead, you can create a list of dictionaries with all those fields:

```py
desc = [
    {
        'name' = 'id', 
        'type' = '', 
        'prescision' = 20,
        ...
    },
    {
        'name' = 'id', 
        'type' = '', 
        'prescision' = 20,
        ...
    },
    ...
]
```

For your test, convert all objects of `ResultSetMetadata` into this list:

```py
resultsSetList = []
for resultSet in desc:
    resultSetObject = {}
    resultSetObject['name'] = resultSet.name
    resultSetObject['type'] = resultSet.type
    resultSetObject['prescision'] = resultSet.prescision
    # Other values you want to compare

    resultsSetList.append(resultSetObject)
```

Alternatively, if you want to compare all possible values:

```py
resultsSetList = [vars(resultSet) for resultSet in desc]
```

Then compare it using your test. `assertCountEqual` compares them regardless of order.